# How to show text on bottom of the image (another div element)?

Tags: html, css

How to show text on bottom of the image (another div element) ?

```
<style type="text/css">
    .right{
  float: left;
  width: 60%;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

.left{
  float: left;
  width: 40%;
  max-width: 303px;
}
  </style>

<div class="left">
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/xCbC4o8.png"/>
</div>
<div class="right">
et’s start with a bit of background. How did you get into angel investing? I was one of the early folks at eBay and by 1999 it was completely overrun by consultants from McKinsey, Bain and BCG. It went from being a cool fun startup to an MBA factory. Angel investing was an outlet for me to hang out with people I liked– startup founders doing crazy stuff! Where did you get the mone et’s start with a bit of background. How did you get into angel investing? I was one of the early folks at eBay and by 1999 it was completely overrun by consultants from McKinsey, Bain and BCG. It went from being a cool fun startup to an MBA factory. Angel investing was an outlet for me to hang out with people I liked– startup founders det’s start with a bit of background. How did you get into angel investing? I was one of the early folks at eBay and by 1999 it was completely overrun by consultants from McKinsey, Bain and BCG. It went from being a cool fun startup to an MBA factory. Angel investing was an outlet for me to hang out with people I liked– startup founders doing crazy stuff! Where did you get the moneoing crazy stuff! Where did you get the mone
et’s start with a bit of background. How did you get into angel investing? I was one of the early folks at eBay and by 1999 it was completely overrun by consultants from McKinsey, Bain and BCG. It went from being a cool fun startup to an MBA factory. Angel investing was an outlet for me to hang out with people I liked– startup founders doing crazy stuff! Where did you get the mone
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/u50z4zta/

When I test my code, it shows like this. Text not showing in bottom of the image [see red square]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mVFpb.jpg

I want to show text on bottom of the image like this. [see red square]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cSuvF.jpg

How can I do that?

Comment: You can put all the content to one div with `width: 100%` (without any `float` properties) and give your image the `float: left` property.

Comment: use HTML5 `<figure>` and `<figcaption>` which is intended exactly for this approach. You can style these symantics accordingly with CSS (answers on this question)

Answer (score 0):

So are you looking something like this one- [LiveFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tjbaezid/wk5vskat/2/)

```css
    .post{
  margin:25px 25px;
}
    

  img {
      float: right;
    }
```

```html
<div class="post">
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/xCbC4o8.png" />

  <div class="right">

    et’s start with a bit of background. How did you get into angel investing? I was one of the early folks at eBay and by 1999 it was completely overrun by consultants from McKinsey, Bain and BCG. It went from being a cool fun startup to an MBA factory.
    Angel investing was an outlet for me to hang out with people I liked– startup founders doing crazy stuff! Where did you get the mone et’s start with a bit of background. How did you get into angel investing? I was one of the early folks at eBay and
    by 1999 it was completely overrun by consultants from McKinsey, Bain and BCG. It went from being a cool fun startup to an MBA factory. Angel investing was an outlet for me to hang out with people I liked– startup founders det’s start with a bit of
    background. How did you get into angel investing? I was one of the early folks at eBay and by 1999 it was completely overrun by consultants from McKinsey, Bain and BCG. It went from being a cool fun startup to an MBA factory. Angel investing was an
    outlet for me to hang out with people I liked– startup founders doing crazy stuff! Where did you get the moneoing crazy stuff! Where did you get the mone et’s start with a bit of background. How did you get into angel investing? I was one of the early
    folks at eBay and by 1999 it was completely overrun by consultants from McKinsey, Bain and BCG. It went from being a cool fun startup to an MBA factory. Angel investing was an outlet for me to hang out with people I liked– startup founders doing crazy
folks at eBay and by 1999 it was completely overrun by consultants from McKinsey, Bain and BCG. It went from being a cool fun startup to an MBA factory. Angel investing was an outlet for me to hang out with people I liked– startup founders doing crazy
folks at eBay and by 1999 it was completely overrun by consultants from McKinsey, Bain and BCG. It went from being a cool fun startup to an MBA factory. Angel investing was an outlet for me to hang out with people I liked– startup founders doing crazy
folks at eBay and by 1999 it was completely overrun by consultants from McKinsey, Bain and BCG. It went from being a cool fun startup to an MBA factory. Angel investing was an outlet for me to hang out with people I liked– startup founders doing crazy
folks at eBay and by 1999 it was completely overrun by consultants from McKinsey, Bain and BCG. It went from being a cool fun startup to an MBA factory. Angel investing was an outlet for me to hang out with people I liked– startup founders doing crazy
folks at eBay and by 1999 it was completely overrun by consultants from McKinsey, Bain and BCG. It went from being a cool fun startup to an MBA factory. Angel investing was an outlet for me to hang out with people I liked– startup founders doing crazy
    stuff! Where did you get the mone
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

just remove all the divs  and simply add `float:left` to the `img`

```css
img {float:left}
```

```html
<img  src="http://i.imgur.com/xCbC4o8.png"/>

et’s start with a bit of background. How did you get into angel investing? I was one of the early folks at eBay and by 1999 it was completely overrun by consultants from McKinsey, Bain and BCG. It went from being a cool fun startup to an MBA factory. Angel investing was an outlet for me to hang out with people I liked– startup founders doing crazy stuff! Where did you get the mone et’s start with a bit of background. How did you get into angel investing? I was one of the early folks at eBay and by 1999 it was completely overrun by consultants from McKinsey, Bain and BCG. It went from being a cool fun startup to an MBA factory. Angel investing was an outlet for me to hang out with people I liked– startup founders det’s start with a bit of background. How did you get into angel investing? I was one of the early folks at eBay and by 1999 it was completely overrun by consultants from McKinsey, Bain and BCG. It went from being a cool fun startup to an MBA factory. Angel investing was an outlet for me to hang out with people I liked– startup founders doing crazy stuff! Where did you get the moneoing crazy stuff! Where did you get the mone
et’s start with a bit of background. How did you get into angel investing? I was one of the early folks at eBay and by 1999 it was completely overrun by consultants from McKinsey, Bain and BCG. It went from being a cool fun startup to an MBA factory. Angel investing was an outlet for me to hang out with people I liked– startup founders doing crazy stuff! Where did you get the mone
```

or without css write inline in HTML

```
<img style="float:left" src="http://i.imgur.com/xCbC4o8.png"/>
```